# Parse HTML to export cell content of specific table

Tags: powershell, html-parsing, getelementsbytagname, invoke-webrequest

There's a HTML file which is exported to a variable using 'Invoke-WebRequest' from where I'd like to export content from a specific table.

$Result = Invoke-WebRequest 'https://www.dailyfaceoff.com/teams/anaheim-ducks/line-combinations'

Unfortunately by using $result.parsedHTML is not returning any result. Hence I was looking at using regex to find the string. This is where I am looking for your help.

Requested actions:

- search within HTML file for table with id=LW1
- within this cell search for <span class=name>Hello World</span>
- export content 'Hello World'

HTML Structure:

```
<body ...>
    <div ...>
        <tbody>
            <td id="LW1">
                <a ....>
                    <span class="player-name">Hello World</span>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tbody>
    </div>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance for any input or help!

Try 1:

```
$r = Invoke-WebRequest 'https://www.dailyfaceoff.com/teams/anaheim-ducks/line-combinations'
$table = $r.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("table")
```

Result 1:
No output, looks like HTML structure is preventing parsing action.

Try 2:

```
$r = Invoke-WebRequest 'https://www.dailyfaceoff.com/teams/anaheim-ducks/line-combinations'
$string = ($r.Content | 
    where {$_ -match '^a href.*LW1.*\ title=.*>/span.*'}) -replace '.*>'
```

Result 2:
Regex not matching

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68728114/3245749) from another question. I think their method of using the Internet Explorer COMObject will serve you well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Please don't try to parse HTML with regex, that's a terrible idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). You can do this in both, PowerShell Core and Windows PowerShell using [Com Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-object?view=powershell-7.2#example-2-create-an-internet-explorer-com-object):

```bash
$com = New-Object -ComObject htmlfile
$com.write([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes(@'
<body>
  <div>
    <tbody>
      <td id="LW1">
        <a><span class="player-name">Hello World</span></a>
      </td>
    </tbody>
  </div>
</body>
'@))

$com.getElementsByClassName('player-name') | ForEach-Object innerHtml
# Outputs: Hello World
$null = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($com)
```

Alternatively, you can use [`XmlDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument?view=net-8.0):

```bash
$xml = [xml]::new()
$xml.LoadXml(@'
<body>
  <div>
    <tbody>
      <td id="LW1">
        <a><span class="player-name">Hello World</span></a>
      </td>
    </tbody>
  </div>
</body>
'@)
$xml.SelectSingleNode("//span[@class='player-name']").InnerText
```

Comment: Hi Santiago,
Many thanks for your valuable input, that's exactly what I need.

Btw, as there are multiple cells with the same class name I had to use an additional object to search first for the cell.